# Java program doesn't terminate

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to create a deadlock using join in threads (JAVA). According to my understanding the below program should terminate. Can somebody please explain why the below program doesn't terminate?

```
public class DeadLockUsingJoins2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AThread a = new AThread(null, "A");
        a.start();
        AThread b = new AThread(a, "B");
        b.start();
        a.t = b;
    }
}

class AThread extends Thread{

    public Thread t;

    public AThread(Thread thread, String name){
        super(name);
        this.t = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            if(t != null)
                t.join();
            else
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
          //  if(t != null)
          //      t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Somebody interruped thread - " + this.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Winding Up thread - " + this.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't read the code yet, but I thought the entire idea of a "deadlock" is when 2 threads compete for a resource and both never get it so the program doesn't terminate.

Comment: AThread b = new AThread("A", "B");

Comment: thread 'B' waits for 'A' to terminate. As soon as 'A' terminates (which happens after sleep), 'B' should also terminate. Isn't it?

Comment: This just works fine.. I do not see any reason why it wont terminate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a pause before a.t = b;

```
    b.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    a.t = b;
```

it will work. But to be reliable it needs syncronization, eg like this

```
public class DeadLockUsingJoins2 {
    public static boolean go;

    public synchronized static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException {
        AThread a = new AThread(null, "A");
        AThread b = new AThread(a, "B");
        a.start();
        while (!go) {
            DeadLockUsingJoins2.class.wait();
        }
        a.t = b;
        b.start();
        DeadLockUsingJoins2.class.notifyAll();
    }
}

class AThread extends Thread {
    public Thread t;

    public AThread(Thread thread, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.t = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (t != null)
                t.join();
            else {
                synchronized (DeadLockUsingJoins2.class) {
                    DeadLockUsingJoins2.go = true;
                    DeadLockUsingJoins2.class.notifyAll();
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Winding Up thread - " + this.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Well, it will probably work for most of the time, but it's not 100% reliable. it's also slowing down the app. I'd use a true synchronization instead.

Comment: @david I agree, my purpose was to give a hint why it hangs, now added synchronization

Answer (score 3):

The only reason i see for not terminating is that your main thread reaches the line

```
a.t = b;
```

before thread "a" reaches the lines

```
if(t != null)
    t.join();
```

if so, the threads wait for each other to terminate.

To make sure you get a deadlock - your class names suggests this - you should reorder your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AThread a = new AThread(null, "A");
    AThread b = new AThread(a, "B");
    a.t = b;
    a.start();
    b.start();
}
```

Comment: @ Marco Forber - Thanks. Simply this is what I intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

It will deadlock if main thread is executed up to `a.t = b;` before `run()` on any of the created threads is actually called. The threads then deadlock on `join()` calls.

EDIT: To avoid this, you need to use some sort of synchronization between the main thread and the threads you're creating. For example, signal the start of `run()` using `Object.notify()` and wait for that using `Object.wait()` in main thread.

Comment: "before run() on any of the created threads is actually called"   - Actually in this example we are not so concerned about thread 'B' right. Because anyways its going to wait on 'A'

Answer (score 1):

So you have successfully written a deadlock, because each of your threads is waiting for the other.

Because the thread run method never finish.

Comment: Can you please explain more as to why run() never finishes. According to my understanding thread 'B' is waiting for 'A'. While 'A' just sleeps for 5 secs and should finish, which should be followed by 'B'. After dry run, I thought this code is incomplete for deadlock, but looks otherwise. Thats what I dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it terminates. The problem appears when thread B starts running (but doesn't pass the `if(t != null)` check) after making `a.t = b`.

When this is the case both threads waits one for the other to finish because of the `join` inside.